# Code sharing between React ES6 Classes

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to dry up a few functions i'm using accross several of my component classes.  Mixins are a no-go and I'm struggling to understand what alternative I'm supposed to use.  Setting the code up as a module seems promising, but I don't understand how to package it so I can use it to extend several different class.

Say I have:

```
class functionsToShare {
  thingToDo(){
    //do a thing
  }
}

export default functionsToShare;
```

I'm assuming in my component class I'd want something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import functionsToShare from 'some/path'
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (

    );
  }
}

export SomeComponent
```

But how do I use the shared class to extend my component?  If I declared it inthe class declaration likemy componenet is delcared to extend React.Component that would defeat the reusability... Is there an alternate way I should be looking at?

Comment: Can't you just do `functionsToShare.thingToDo()`?

Comment: I suppose I could.  In this case that will work nicely.

Is there no way to extend the classes so that the module class bring in new instance methods or expands the class' prototype functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your shared functions file as a file with several functions that you need to use, each function being exported as a named export. Like this:

```
export function thingToDo() {
    ...
}

export function getUserByEmail(email) {
    ...
}
```

Save this file as `functionsToShare.js`, for example.

Then in each React component class (or anywhere else) you can import that functions, just ones you need by:

```
import {thingToDo} from "./functionsToShare"; // import a function
thingToDo(); // call function
```

or all of them by:

```
import * as somename from "./functionsToShare";  // import all functions from that file
somename.thingToDo();   // call specific function
```